# JobStorage.Current property value has not been initialized

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, hangfire, nunit-3.0

Don't get me wrong! This question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52113361/jobstorage-current-property-value-has-not-been-initialized-you-must-set-it-befo) before but it didn't get any answer (that works) or it also does not similar to my.

I have a ASP.net Web API running .net 4.5 that use Hangfire v1.7.2

In `Startup.cs` I have:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureAuth(app);

            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage("myDbConnString");
            app.UseHangfireDashboard("/hangfire", new DashboardOptions()
            {
                Authorization = new[] { new HangfireAuthorizationFilter() }
            });

            app.UseHangfireServer();
        }
```

In `MyController.cs` I have Hangfire enque a job that execute DoSomething()

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostPerson(Person p)
{      
    // spin up a new dedicated thread and execut the job
    BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => DoSomething(p.Id));

    return OK;
}
```

If I test with Postman tool trying to call the my web API HTTPPost method I see my code execute **nicely** and everything good.

**However**, when I am using `NUnit Test V3` to unit-test the MyController.cs I am having an issue when hitting this line in the controller `BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => DoSomething(p.Id));`

```
[Test]
public void Post()
{
     MyController controller = new MyController();
     Person p = new Person
     {
         data = "hello world"
     };

     var actionResult = controller.PostPerson(p);
}
```

Stack trace:

> at Hangfire.JobStorage.get_Current()    at
>   Hangfire.BackgroundJob.<>c.<.cctor>b__45_0()    at
>   System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()    at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()    at
>   Hangfire.BackgroundJob.Enqueue(Expression`1 methodCall)    at
>   myApp.Controllers.MyController.d__3.MoveNext()

Error msg:

> JobStorage.Current property value has not been initialized. You must
>   set it before using Hangfire Client or Server API.

Please help me with what is the issue here and how to fix it.

Thank you!

Comment: Tightly coupled to implementation concerns make it difficult to unit test in isolation. Encapsulate the `BackgroundJob.Enqueue` behind an abstraction so you can test your controller in isolation with out knock on effect of hangfire

Comment: @Nkosi can you elaborate with some code? I have been following this `https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/writing-unit-tests.html` but it just lead to many other error.

Comment: @CB4 have you found an answer to your questions yet?