# Do hangfire recurring jobs need to be in program.cs?

Tags: c#, hangfire, .net-7.0

I am using .Net 7 and Hangfire 1.8.5

Do all of hangfire's recurring jobs have to be listed directly in Program.cs ? Or can I abstract them out into a sub module? I'd rather have 20 recurring jobs in a seperate module than all in Program.cs

Program.cs :

```
app.UseHangfireDashboard();
app.MapHangfireDashboard();

// Hangfire Recurring Jobs
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<MyTestService>("Test Job", (x) => x.testJob("hangfire test 
job"), Cron.Daily(8, 30));
....to infitity...
```

Could I have instead...

Program.cs :

```
app.UseHangfireDashboard();
app.MapHangfireDashboard();

BackgroundJobs jobs = new BackgroundJobs();
jobs.MyRecurringJobs();
```

I assume I'd need to pass something into this new BackgroundJobs class? How would I setup hangfire to work this way?

Comment: `AddOrUpdate` is a static method on `RecurringJob`. Why would it matter where you call it from, so long as you call it?

Comment: Also, if your storage is persistent, I don't think you need to call it every time your application starts.

Comment: Did you try it first? You can put those calls anywhere you like.

Comment: I was after the standard practice example of how to use hangfire, DenisMichael.K's answer was what I was looking for. I didn't want to use it in a way no one else does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `hangfire` recurring jobs do not need to be in `program.cs`. As others have pointed out [RecurringJob](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/blob/master/src/Hangfire.Core/RecurringJob.cs) is a static class and can be called anywhere from your code.

However if you want to call it in `program.cs` separately. I would use a  static class as below:

```
public static class HangfireWorker
{
  public static void StartRecurringJobs(this IApplicationBuilder app)
  {
   RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("test_job", () => TestJob("hangfire test job"), 
            Cron.Daily(8, 30));
                    }
        //to infinity
}
```

Then in my `program.cs` proceed to call `app.StartRecurringJobs();`

Also incase you face issue [jobstorage.Current not initialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52113361/jobstorage-current-property-value-has-not-been-initialized-you-must-set-it-befo) on startup you might need to initialize the [Jobstorage.Current](https://discuss.hangfire.io/t/jobstorage-current-property-value-has-not-been-initialized/884)

Comment: Thanks for the guidance! Every example I'd seen online was using them in program.cs and this reply shows me good standard practice of how to abstract them.